# What can I expect when I run out of ids on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would never create enough entities to run out of 63-bit address space, but say I used allocateIdRange to allocate the id 9223372036854775807 (which is almost 2^63).  Is that kind of entity just broken for new, automatically entered entities?

I tried this out in a test app . It seems that some shards of the auto-IDer can continue to produce valid ids, but other shards just give a `DatastoreFailureException`.  The success rate is about 30%.  Will it ever go up?

This is actually a serious question because, in my naivete, I created some rather huge ids.  I still have several trillion entities to go before I come up to this limit, but I've noticed that the ids can jump by millions between entities, and I enter new entities at the rate of about a million per year.  So... I'm scared of hitting this limit.

Comment: You can use incremental id and it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I use incremental id?  In my tests, the default allocation that appengine does stops working.

Comment: As long as you don't create any more huge ids I think you'll be okay. I believe the gaps between ids come from resets in the local counters used to allocate ids. You can imagine how it works: Various shards of the datastore use the internal equivalent of allocate_ids to request e.g. 100 ids and then hand those out to new entities; if a shard is killed any ids it didn't hand out yet are forever reserved. I you're generating new ids at a rate of a million per year I would think that most shards get to hand out plenty of ids before they die. You could sample ids for a month and predict the rate.

Comment: My concern is that all new ids might be huge. It's now been a day since I reserved keyrange [`2^63-1`, `2^63`] and still 12 out of 20 attempts to put a new entity fail with `DatastoreFailureException`.  There seems to be one shard giving out ids on the magnitude of 100000, but it comes up less than half the time.

Either way, if I'm going to run out of ids I think I have at least a year to see it coming and, for example, rewrite all of my entities to a new kind with ids starting at 1.  Thanks for your help - it's very nice to hear from AppEngine staff!

Comment: It has now been 2 days since I reserved the high keys, and now 100% of   my new entities results in `DatastoreFailureException`.  I guess the working shard got killed and all that was retained was the max id given out so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a test app I reserved a bunch of very high ids with `allocateIdRange`.  At first, about half of my attempts to put new entities succeeded. Now, **no** new entities can be put with a blank id - a `DatastoreFailureException` is raised every time.  I presume this is because the key allocator implementation does not keep track of gaps in keys, but only keeps track of the highest id given out so far.

I don't see any way to reset the counter for this Kind, so I think the only solution would be to pick a new `Kind` name.

Lesson: don't use ids anywhere near 2^63!